# flutter doctor "Connected device (the doctor check crashed)" and it is unable to run "adb" on Windows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I startet the Default Flutter Project in Android Studio to continue a Tutorial that I started a while ago, when I started it the last time everything was fine, but this time The Emulated Device wasn't updating the changes from the script, then I looked at the flutter doctor an saw this Error but the adb file is in the right directory. In Android Studio it also Says "* failed to start daemon"[[image: flutter doctor Error]]

I looked at the Directory it was showing but the file was ther, so I Looked at some other People who had the same Problem but nothing worked. I downloaded the latest platform-tools folder from the Androide Studio page but it still won't work.

Comment: adb is not installed, install it manually.

Comment: how do i do that?